# Add weight to edge in Network

Tags: python, list, networkx

I have created 2 list. Then I have created another list  in which there are many couple of number (x,y), It's the mix between the both list.
Then, i have count the number of occurrence of this couple in my list.
Now, I want to create some edges with a weight.

Here is my code :

```
 G = nx.Graph()
 G.add_nodes_from(ID)
 L = []
 ID_1 = df_2['ID_1']
 ID_2 = df_2['ID_2']
 L2 = ID_1 # First List
 L3 = ID_2 #Second List
 L = list(zip(L2, L3)) # Fusion of the list
 #print(L)
 compte = {}.fromkeys(set(L),0)
 for valeur in L:
    compte[valeur] += 1
 print(compte) # Return occurence the couple (a,b)
```

Here is what python return :

```
{(1295, 1485): 1, (232, 941): 1, (28, 653): 50, (376, 1336): 2, (214, 254): 
 3, (202, 954): 1, (1212, 1342): 13, (117, 587): 5, (131, 256): 3, (1216, 
 1232): 1, (190, 836): 2, (798, 921): 2, (32, 893): 1, (376, 1228): 53, (269, 
 836): 9, (90, 605): 2, (184, 240): 22, (63, 179): 717, (240, 778): 4, (413, 
 706): 6, (72, 147): 20, (1237, 1412): 2, (116, 190): 3, (85, 382): 3, (353, 
1594): 1, (214, 267): 5, (227, 960): 1, (290, 491): 1, (450, 480): 3, (1214, 
1401): 5, (205, 649): 5, (743, 998): 1, (440, 960): 1, (1336, 1512): 6, (214, 
388): 1, (267, 480): 6, (79, 200): 4, (101, 447): 26, (92, 893): 1, (1232, 
 1805): 8, (339, 504): 10, (306, 327): 1, (176, 254): 34, (267, 601): 1, 
 (179, 488): 1, (184, 603): 1, (1366, 1512): 1, (464, 886): 4, (257, 327): 1, 
 (480, 601): 16, (265, 447): 3, (638, 958): 121, (424, 440): 4}
```

As you can see, i have many couple of number [(x,y):z] with z the occurence.
Now, I want to create edge (x,y,weight : z) with x the first node, y the second node and z the weight. But i don't know how to code it, have you some recommandation?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your code and output as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(edge[0],edge[1],weight) for edge,weight in compte.items()])
```